# "Weightned" reputation nodes

Tags: blockchain

I am new to the blockchain world, therefore I have a general understanding of the concept but mainly as a user.

Is it there a way so that the reputation of a node depends on some sort of action taken by other nodes? In the same way, the "quantity" of reputation that a node is able to confer to another depends on its reputation.

The objective of this strategy is to create a validation network in which everyone can grow but their growth is based on the reputation gained by other nodes.

thanks to anyone who can contribute

Answer (score 0):

On top of the blockchain platforms, various reputation schemes are often built for participants, however, as far as I know, in the technical consensus protocols of the blockchain platform themselves, "reputation" is used only in a "binary" form, and then in the case of using a pool of dedicated validators (this is how it works Ripple).

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, do you think it is something that can be implemented in an existing blockchain schema or would it require a full rebuild from the ground up?